# Intel VTune unable to locate all Windows debug symbols

Tags: windows, debugging, profiling, debug-symbols, intel-vtune

I have created a project with CMake, which I now tried to profile using the trial version of Intel VTune together with Visual Studio 15. I set the Windows debug symbol server in Visual Studio, but VTune is unable to find all the symbols. My project is configured for debugging ofcourse.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1) I can copy the QT .pdb files to the project folder to resolve their location, but adding the QT bin directory to the list of symbol locations as in the picture above doesn't help.

2) It still doesn't find some of the Windows debugging symbols and therefore alot of the function calls don't show a proper name. I've also tried to manually run 'symchk.exe', but it says "FAILED - ... mismatched or not found" for all of the files in the system32 folder.

I had all of this working before, but now I formatted my computer and can't get it to work again. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: I also started to realize that there is no callstack information available. I downloaded the Windows symbols manually now as well, which still didn't help. I'm starting to wonder if it's really the missing symbols though...

Comment: Which VTune version do you use?
As for stacks - please make sure you're running Basic Hotspots or Advanced Hotspots with stacks option enabled. The default setting for Advanced Hotspots doesn't collect call stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. I'm using Intel VTune Amplifier 2017 Update 2 (build 499904). Someone on the Intel forums told me that my Windows version (build 15063) is currently not supported, but will be after the upcoming update 3. He sent me an updated driver, so now everything works as expected!